# How can I know the specific information of the monthly average data?

Tags: satellite, noaa

I know that the "google earth engine" site provides NOAA's VIIRS-DNB VCMSLCFG information.

This is the monthly average data.
The satellite photographs the entire earth twice a day, and I want to know which data was calculated.

In other words, I want to know which images was calculated as monthly average data.

But I can't find out about this.
I ask for help with this.

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask about it may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can see dataset availability, product description and bands in following link: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_VIIRS_DNB_MONTHLY_V1_VCMSLCFG#bands